# Magento 1.9.2.3 Unknown cipher in list: TLSv1

Tags: magento-1.9

I installed the last Magento version 1.9.2.3 and i tried to install a extension via Magento Connect in admin painel and i got the error:

Unknown cipher in list: TLSv1

I tried this solution:

In file downloader/lib/Mage/HTTP/Client/Curl.php find the code

> $this->curlOption(CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST, 'TLSv1');

and then change to

> if(isset($var)){$this->curlOption(CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST, 'TLSv1');}

I didn't find the code above in file curl.php but i can find that code in Magento v1.9.2.2 in curl.php.

How can i solve this? Thanks.

Comment: Upgrade your cURL extension

Comment: @RobbieAverill why he needs to do this??

Comment: Because it looks like cURL doesn't recognise the TLSv1 cipher, which it should, so it's probably an old version

Comment: Thanks for answered Robbie, as you said, i found an article that said that this is a bug in Magento as it relates to centOS servers with older legacy curl programs and to fix it, in curl.php file, i replaced this code: 

$this->curlOption(CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST, 'TLSv1');

to this: 

$this->curlOption(CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1); 

and now it's working as well. Actually, my Magento store 1.9.2.3 is running with this settings: 

CentOS 6.7
Curl 7.12.1
PHP 5.2.17 

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

latest magento files:

```
[root@gun magento]# grep -i -r  TLS downloader/*
downloader/lib/Mage/HTTP/Client/Curl.php:        $this->curlOption(CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST, 'TLSv1');
[root@gun magento]# php -r "require 'app/Mage.php'; echo Mage::getVersion();"
1.9.2.3[root@gun magento]#
```

you have probably some cache or customizations, or broken installation.